# ASP.NET MVC2 Ajax ActionLink calls wrong action

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, actionlink

I am trying to change some data on my page using Ajax. This is a piece of code that does it:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Rate Up", "RatePost", new { postId = post.Id, rating = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = string.Format("postRating_{0}", count) })%>
```

The problem is that RatePost action is not called after click on this link. Instead, the parent view action is being called. How can I avoid this and just call the RatePost action with parameters I specified?

Comment: what is the code inside your `RatePost` action method?

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be correct.

Verify that you included the **Microsoft Ajax scripts** in your view:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript">/script>  
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If something fails in the javascript generated by `Ajax.ActionLink`, the click action is not cancelled.